# Download video file for website based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website currently loads a video in the banner when a desktop user visits the webpage. Currently the video is hidden but will still download if the user is on a mobile device. I would like to keep the video from downloading if the screen size below a certain count. I'm not sure how to go about this, I know of the `display:none` that can go along with CSS but this still downloads the file which is something I'd rather not do if the video isn't going to show at all.

Comment: you need javascript to detect screen size, and only insert the "download the video" stuff if the screen size is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first check to see if the screen is the appropriate width and then load your video source. Something like this should get you started.

```
var videoElem = document.querySelector('video');
var yourThreshold = 600;
if (screen.availWidth >= yourThreshold) {
  videoElem.append('<source src="yourVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"');
}
```

You can of course decide how specific you want to be as far as targeting devices. Just the width alone might not suffice.

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is fine, here's something you can try:

```
$(function(){
    if($(window).width()>640){ //add video only if screen width is above 640px
        $("body").append(yourVideoHere);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you are trying to load the video, I would recommend the HTML5 video element with the preload attribute set to none so the video does not automatically begin to download. You could also then look at using a script that allows you to swap out video files depending on screen resolution, so for mobile you could load a smaller video size, a script that can get you up and running quickly is enquire.js. Hope this helps.

```
<video poster="image-location.jpg" preload="none">
    <source class="mp4" src="video-location.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source class="webm" src="video-location.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source class="ogg" src="video-location.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <!-- Fallback Content such as embed YouTube video-->
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to do it based on screen size**

see the other answers, measure screen size with javascript and only add the video tag, or set the source, if the screen size is big enough.

There's a gotcha if you use jquery as the `<video>` functions like `.play()` are javascript functions and won't be available to a jquery object.

**How to actually do it**

The best current solution for the problem of avoiding sending large video files to devices that haven't got the available bandwidth to handle it is currently server side and relies on the much more reliable metric of actual bandwidth. This is [what YouTube do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqQk7kLuaK4).

Consider the following two scenarios:

1. I'm at home, I have my smart phone connected by wifi to my high speed internet connection and the signal is good, but my screen resolution is reported as 480px - why should I be denied a video?
2. I'm out of the house, I've connected to wifi on a train, but the signal is horrible, my screen size reports as 1600px so I get a huge video, your site doesn't load and I go visit your competitor.

You can find out more about this [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video),  and about one of the key tools, [ffmpeg here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), or you can use [Any Video Converter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/) to do a similar thing in a desktop GUI if you have full control over the videos. It's complicated and difficult and you may be better off using a third party service.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply, but the change from mobile to desktop has less to do with bandwidth (which is a bullet point but not what I want to worry about) and more to do with how the site is going to look on mobile vs desktop. Desktop has a wider screen which the video looks great on, mobile is too small and the video looks compressed and the site gets messy.

Comment: Ok, the question isn't really phrased like that as you talk about avoiding downloading - if you aren't concerned about bandwidth, use display none?

Comment: You might also find some way of delivering videos cropped at different aspect ratios based on device screen size, which would be tricky video editing wise but really slick